# CentOS 7 SSH errors

Tags: shell, centos, ssh

having a bit of an issue with SSH and my CentOS 7 server.
Here's a description of my problem.

I have open-ssh setup on my server, and am able to ssh in as root (The server is a remote server, and open-ssh/centos 7 was setup by default). However, I cannot ssh in as another user, but I can do things like SFTP as that user.

In /var/log/messages it says:

```
Mar  7 22:10:04 mail systemd: Started Hostname Service.
Mar  7 22:10:42 mail systemd-logind: New session 1107 of user -----.
Mar  7 22:10:42 mail systemd: Started Session 1107 of user -----.
Mar  7 22:10:42 mail systemd: Starting Session 1107 of user -----.
Mar  7 22:10:42 mail systemd-logind: Removed session 1107.
```

(I have removed the username for security)

While on the client's end it says:

```
2016-03-08 03:37:29    Sent password
2016-03-08 03:37:29    Access granted
2016-03-08 03:37:29    Opening session as main channel
2016-03-08 03:37:29    Server unexpectedly closed network connection
```

I have not edited the base sshd config that was given with the server yet.
Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Normally I use XRDP for Remote Desktop Access into the server, but I need to allow SSH access for another user to start/stop a process.

Comment: what do you see in server log `/var/log/secure`? It should tell you more.

Comment: Try running your ssh client with "-v" or even "-vv" ... it will probably give you some useful info.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, the user you are using might be configured to use `sftp` only like:

```
Match User myuser
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Or the shell of the user may be set to something special, check the file `/etc/passwd`

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was with the permissions of ChrootDirectory directory. Ehh, who cares about the custom permissions? I shall give the universal permissions, so that everything will covered in it. IS that what you thought before setting the permissions? Apparently, that is not how it works for Linux.

I had a team coming up to me complaining about their new SFTP not working as expected, and when checked the permissions of the custom directory, they were set to 777, so I just had to reset them to 755 recursively, and got to be called Messiah.

Cheers, happy learning!